# From array to complex string format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I currently have a function which returns this array:

```
var myArray = [
    { Sepal_Width: { Average_Sepal_Width: series => series.average() } },
    { Sepal_Width: { Sum_Sepal_Width: series => series.sum() } },
    { Petal_Length: { Average_Petal_Length: series => series.average() } }
]
```

But I need the output to look like this:

```
Sepal_Width: { 
     Average_Sepal_Width: series => series.average(),
     Sum_Sepal_Width: series => series.sum() 
},
Petal_Length: { 
     Average_Petal_Length: series => series.average() 
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is even possible, as I need to account for the user adding additional lines to the original array like `{ Petal_Length: Sum_Petal_Length: series => series.sum() }}` and have this automatically go within the Petal_Length: {}.

```
Sepal_Width: { 
     Average_Sepal_Width: series => series.average(),
     Sum_Sepal_Width: series => series.sum() 
},
Petal_Length: { 
     Average_Petal_Length: series => series.average() },
     Sum_Petal_Length: series => series.sum() }
}
```

Comment: What datatype are those values? `series => series.average()`. Is it a function? (myArray)

Comment: Why? In any case, there's no trivial way to get it formatted like this, especially if you want to keep the function source code available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the first key and assign the values to the given key at the result object.

```js
var array = [{ Sepal_Width: { Average_Sepal_Width: series => series.average() } }, { Sepal_Width: { Sum_Sepal_Width: series => series.sum() } }, { Petal_Length: { Average_Petal_Length: series => series.average() } }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => Object.assign(r[k] = r[k] || {}, v));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful but I'm trying to understand what the code is doing in words, haha -- I think that `Object.entries` turns the object into k,v pairs within an array [[k,v],[k,v]], but I'm confused what's going on with the `Object.assign` to get these values into the format I want. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: right. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of key/value arrays, the later [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes a target object and assigns the following object to it, after taking a property with the name `k` or it creates a new object for it.

Comment: ...So it turns out each of my objects within the array are actually being returned as a string (UGH) I thought `JSON.parse` would help me but to no avail. Any ideas? I've reproduced my issue here https://repl.it/@MayaJaffe/string-manipulation Thank you again for your help, I'm learning so much!

Comment: it is only possible to use `eval` and generate an object from the string. it is not possible to parse it as [JSON](https://json.org/), because it does not comply with the specs.